L-Section Impedance-Matching using the Q-Factor
im trying desperately to match a 480-Ohm to 50-Ohm impedance: 
I have made the calculations and determined C=-j3.38nF and L=-j81.1uH (reactive). The inductance seems to have capacitive behavior and im certain i made a mistake. NOTE: Im not using and i don't want to use a Smith Chart for this. These are my calculations so far:$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Matching Network:} \\
1. \quad & Q_s = \left| \frac{X_s}{Z_s} \right| \implies |X_s| = Z_s \cdot Q_s \implies Z_s = R_p, \quad X_s = \frac{wC_p}{G_p} \\
2. \quad & Q_p = \left| \frac{B_p}{G_p} \right| \implies |B_p| = Q_p \cdot G_p, \quad B_p = G_s, \quad G_p = wL_m \\
3. \quad & Q_d = \sqrt{\frac{R_p}{R_s} - 1} \implies Q = \approx j0.94 \\
3 \rightarrow 1: \quad & X_s = Q_s \cdot Z_s \approx j0.94 \cdot 50\Omega \approx j47\Omega \implies C = \frac{1}{wX_s} \approx \frac{1}{2\pi \cdot 1\text{MHz} \cdot j47\Omega} \approx -j3.386 \cdot 10^{-9}F \\
3 \rightarrow 2: \quad & X_p = Q_p \cdot R_p \approx \frac{480 \Omega}{j0.94} \approx -j510\Omega \implies L = \frac{X_p}{w} \approx \frac{-510\Omega}{2\pi \cdot 1\text{MHz}} \approx j81.4 \cdot 10^{-5}H \approx -j81.4\mu H
\end{aligned}
$$
What must i do to correctly define a matching-network that matches my 480-Ohm with a 50-Ohm resistor?
Im ultimately teaching myself here so i don't have someone to talk about this. Therefore, any help will be greatly appreciated!

What is your question? Please ask a specific question.

define s21 and BW

to get something like this https://i.sstatic.net/TOxwSYJj.png ??

@VoltageSpike Yes, i added one

Q can not have an imaginary value. Turn your network around and go from low impedance Rs = 50 Ohm to high impedance Rp = 480 Ohm.
Q = SQR [(Rp / Rs) - 1]
You need a series Xs and a parallel/shunt branch Xp for the matching network:
Xs = Rs * Q
Xp = Rp / Q
As a lowpass matching network:
Ls = Xs / w
Cp = 1 / (w * Xp)
w = 2 * Pi * f
As a highpass matching network:
Cs = 1 / (w * Xs)
Lp = Xp / w
w = 2 * Pi * f

Thank you, but i can't turn my network around

You "turn it around" just for calculation of the matching network components, not in your actual circuit.

Can you explain why you turn it around please?

The equation you used for calculating Q is only valid if Rs < Rp. In case Rs > Rp use Q = SQR [(Rs / Rp) - 1]. Q is a real, positive number larger than 1, it can not be j0. 94.

That worked! Do you have any reference that can explain this?
